# Could not find or load main class in eclipse using maven and scala

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, scala-ide

I am using the Scala IDE.
I have created one Scala project and wrote simple scala object i.e.

```
object Test {
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
eprintln("hi")
}}
```

It's running as expected.

After that I have converted my project to a maven project.

I did Clean and install.

after that if I am trying to run my scala class, I am getting below error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What did you do to convert it? What does your file structure look like? Please post your `pom.xml`

Comment: Does your `package` match the folder structure of your Main? Somehow Eclipse has issues if it doesn't match

Comment: <project...>

  <artifactId>JavaTriang</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>

Comment: Hi Pim, Can you please explain elaborately.

Comment: In Java if a class is in `package x.y.z` it must also be in `src\main\scala\x\y\z` for it to compile. In scala this is not a requirement. So you can have a class in `package x.y.z` and put the source file in `src\main\scala\x\y` and it will still compile successful. However if this is your main class Eclipse will not be able to recognise it a class containing a main.